# Table filling with 2 properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G= \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \}$ and assume $G$ is a group under an operation $*$ with these properties

(i) $a*b \leq a+b$  $\forall a, b \in G$

(ii) $a*a=0$  $\forall a \in G$

write out the operation table for $G$

---

**Its leq im fixing it**

hint1: if  $ab=ac$ in a group $G$, then  $b=c$

hint2: each element of a finite group G appears exactly once in each row and exactly once in each column of the operation table

___________________________________________________________________--

From property 2 there will be bunch of zeros going down the diagonal

so far the **8s are just nonsense like a blank**

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
1 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
2 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
3 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
4 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
5 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
6 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8   \\ \hline
7& 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

for the first row  $$ 0*1 \leq 0+1$$

that is for whole row

$$\begin{aligned}
0*1  & \leq 1 
\\   0*2  & \leq  2
\\   0*3  & \leq 3 
\\   0*4  & \leq 4 
\\   0*5  & \leq 5 
\\   0*6  & \leq 6 
\\   0*7  & \leq 7  
\end{aligned} $$

things will fall as $0*7=7, \dots ,0*1=1$

so far the table obtained by the properties seems commutative
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 8   \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0 & 8   \\ \hline
7& 7 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

**Does this process needs to be repeated 6 more times??? is there some cool way to do it????**

Comment: You must have $1*2=3$, $1*4=5$, $1*6=7$, $2*4=6$, and then everything else follows.

Comment: Please share the source of this problem. Although, know it is late; but the relevance increases, for learners, by knowing the source. Also, will help in viewing the problem afresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems a bit like a sudoku :)

**I assume, that by $+$ you mean adding modulo 8.**

See, that for for every $k$ and $x\leq k$, $x\neq k-x$ we have
$$x*(k-x)=k=x+(k-x)$$
We have then:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & .   \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & . & .   \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 7 & . & . & .   \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 0 & . & . & .   \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 6 & 7 & . & . & 0 & . & .   \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 7 & . & . & . & . & 0 & .   \\ \hline
7 & 7 & . & . & . & . & . & . & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}
We can now place missing $2$ in row and column for 1, missing 6 in row/column for 3 and missing 5 in row/column for 6 and 7:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 2   \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & . & .   \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 7 & . & . & 6   \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 0 & . & . & .   \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 6 & 7 & . & . & 0 & . & .   \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 7 & . & . & . & . & 0 & 5   \\ \hline
7 & 7 & 2 & . & 6 & . & . & 5 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

See, that (beginning form right) we can easilly fill the row/column for 5
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 2   \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & . & .   \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 7 & 1 & . & 6   \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 2 & . & .   \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 4   \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 7 & . & . & . & 3 & 0 & 5   \\ \hline
7 & 7 & 2 & . & 6 & . & 4 & 5 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

And missing 2 in row/column for 3:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 2   \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & . & .   \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 6   \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 2 & . & .   \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 4   \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 7 & . & 2 & . & 3 & 0 & 5   \\ \hline
7 & 7 & 2 & . & 6 & . & 4 & 5 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

In row/column for 2 there are 1 and 4 mising. Because $7*5=4$, it must be $7*2=1$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 2   \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 1   \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 6   \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 2 & . & .   \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 4   \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 2 & . & 3 & 0 & 5   \\ \hline
7 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 6 & . & 4 & 5 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

Now it is just placing missing 1 in row/column for 6 and missing 3 in row/column for 7:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
* &  0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 2   \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 1   \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 6   \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 2 & \color{red}1 & 3   \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 4   \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 2 & \color{red}1 & 3 & 0 & 5   \\ \hline
7 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

But... wait! Why the 1s we just put in this array are glowing red? See, that
$$6+4=2>1$$
So **there is no operation satisfying your conditions.**

Comment: It is not clear to me why you assumed that addition was modulo $8$, which was not stated in the problem.

Comment: @DerekHolt Just for fun - the problem seems a lot more interesting (and unfortunately leads to that sad conclusion, that there is no solution). If we skip this assumption, after step 2 we can just start filling the table just like a sudoku.